# Scrollable tabs in slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, coda-slider

I've been struggling to get this code to work for the whole day now..
I have a (content) slider (using the Coda Slider plugin) which contains more tabs then visible by default. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to make the tabs scrollable, meaning when you arrived at the last visible tab and click next, it should become visible. Exactly the same as the jQuery UI scrollable plugin does ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LtmA5/1/) and [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-scrollable-tabs/)).

I could switch to this but unfortunately I need to stick with the Coda slider plugin..

I've tried to use the code of the scrollable jQuery UI but without success.
Basically I need to write 2 functions (see my code below), one when you click directly on the tab (which changed to current state) and another one when you click prev/next.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/epnDK/1/)

Any ideas?

Function when user clicks prev/next

```
$('.coda-nav-left, .coda-nav-right').click(function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('coda-nav-left')) {
    $('.coda ul li').remove('.coda ul li:first');
  } else {
    $('.coda ul li'). remove('.coda ul li:last');
  }
});
```

Function when user clicks on a tab and class changes to current

```
function current() {
  var $current = $('.coda-nav ul li a.current');
  if (current) {
    //show next/prev tab next to and sibling from current..
  }
}
```